# why update button for grid view is not firing?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `grid-view` which has property `AutoGenerateEditButtonSet` to true. 
On edit click update cancel was working fine until i add footer template that do enter a row for customer to the database, the footer template had link button add and cancel that take value of row and update on add link button click, the add link button has got validation for all the footer template values to insert in the database, but the weird problem i am facing is that now update button that appears on edit click do not trigger, i have been toiling for link and went through many forums but could not get how to fix this problem, please help me with this, the update button also causing causes validation for the footer content, how to stop it? Please suggest me

the update button become at run time like this..

javascript:`WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new` `WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$MainContent$customerDetailGrid$ctl02$ctl00", "", true, "", "", false, true))`

Comment: add `validationGroup="GroupName"` property to the buttons in the footer

Comment: You can specify one Validation Group for footer buttons and text boxes like `validationgroup="footerValGrp"`

Comment: i did the same but do not work

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the update panel and grid view inside the update panel so remove the update panel then run the application and check weather update button is working or not if working then you can now put the update panel then it will work other wise post your code so that i will check